# Show that one can always find a person with both their neighbours as girls if there are $25$ girls and $25$ boys seated around a circular table

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math

> There are $25$ girls and $25$ boys seated around a circular table. Show that you can always find someone with both their neighbours as girls.

I know that this question has been asked here before, and I understand the solutions given there (for the most part). However, I have a different solution.

Assume that there is a seating where no one has both their neighbours as girls. Hence, each person can either have $2$ boys as neighbours or $1$ girl and $1$ boy as neighbours. Ask each person to count how many boys they have as neighbours and how many girls they have as neighbours. If we add up these respective numbers, we get twice the number of boys and twice the number of girls, since each person is counted twice.

Let there be $k$ people who have $2$ boys as their neighbours, where $k$ is a whole number satisfying $k\leq50.$ Then, $50-k$ people have $1$ girl and $1$ boy as their neighbours. Hence, we get
$$25=\frac{2k+50-k}{2},$$
$$25=\frac{50-k}{2}.$$

The first equation counts the number of boys, and the second counts the number of girls.

These equations imply that $k=0.$ Hence, every person has $1$ boy and $1$ girl next to them.

Let girls be represented with a $G$ and boys with a $B.$ Start out with a boy. WLOG, let there be a girl to his left. This looks like $GB.$ Now, from the discussion above, we know that a boy must be to the right of this boy. This looks like $GBB.$ Now, the rightmost boy must have a girl to his right. This makes it $GBBG.$ The rightmost girl must have a girl to her right. This looks like $GBBGG.$ We can continue like this to see that we form chains of $GBBG.$ We continue this process for $12$ chains. At this point, $24$ girls and $24$ boys have been seated. Now, this rightmost girl must have $2$ boys right next to her which is impossible since only $1$ boy is left. This is a contradiction, and hence our initial assumption is wrong.

Is this solution right? I'm skeptical because I don't really use the parity of $25,$ which other solutions seem to make us of. Well, I guess I kind of implicitly use parity when I deduce that there is one boy "missing".

Comment: **Hint.** Suppose that instead of one big table you have two tables, each seating 25 persons. Can you show that, no matter how you seat the 25 boys and 25 girls at those two tables, two girls will be sitting next to each other?

Comment: @bof, yes, I can show that. Since there must be atleast $13$ girls at some table, the result follows. This solution of yours corresponds to a solution I saw where every second person is asked to stand up and we count the number of standing girls. Is my proof right, though?

Comment: This solution is correct. You essentially show that the arrangement must be $BBGG,BBGG,BBGG,\ldots, BBGG$, so the number of girls must be even. That's how the parity of 25 comes in.

Comment: @CalvinLin, thanks, that makes sense.